# Convergence in the resolvent sense and spectral properties

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $\{T_k\}_k, T$ be unbounded selfadjoint operators on a Hilbert space $H$. If $T_k\to T$ in the norm-resolvent sense, then for any $(a,b)\subset \mathbb R$ with $\{a,b\}\cap \sigma(T)=\emptyset$, the spectral projections $P_{(a,b)}(T_k)\to P_{(a,b)}(T)$ converge in norm. This in particular means that the spectrum of the limiting operator cannot suddenly contract. There is also a similar statement that assures us that the spectrum cannot suddenly expand. From *[Reed,Simon,"Methods in modern mathematical physics", vol. 1]*.

While reading another paper, I came across a sequence of selfadjoint operators satisfying, for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{C-R}$,
$$\|\Pi_FR(\lambda, T_k)\Pi_F-\Pi_FR(\lambda,T)\Pi_F\|\to 0.$$
$\Pi$ is the orthogonal projection and $F$ is a subspace of $H$. What does this convergence imply in terms of spectral invariances? I guess we lose information about the eigenvalues in $F^\perp$ but I wouldn't know how to formalize it. The authors skipped describing the spectral implications.